# Usage of response_type="code token" in OAuth 2?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

The OpenID Connect Spec [OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type Encoding Practices](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#Combinations) states that multiple response_type can be combined, e.g. `response_type="code token"`. Now I'm wondering what it's good for to request an authorization code **and** the token. Isn't the auth code superfluous if you have the token already?

Answer (score 5):

OAuth 2.0 is a protocol framework on top of which other protocols can be built and OpenID Connect is an example of such a protocol.

Especially for OpenID Connect it makes sense to use combined response types because there are 2 tokens in play: the access_token and the id_token. Using "response_type" the client can request how each of the tokens should be delivered.

In the example that that you give, the access_token will be delivered through the front channel as part of the authentication response but the id_token will be delivered when exchanging the "code" for an id_token at the token endpoint in a backchannel call.

A reason for doing this may be that the id_token, which is a signed JWT, does not have to be verified locally when obtained from a proper TLS protected token endpoint, so the client code can be simple. The access_token is opaque to the client anyhow and does not benefit from that.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen this used in practice. Yes, having the token already kind of diminishes the value of using the code flow.